# MVC5 Saving Updated Data Error always require to upload new file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to save data after i edited back to database. The problem is with the file upload. I have to upload new image everytime i want to save edited data otherwise the controller would think that my img property is null. So i rewrite my edit action to like this, hoping it'd use my uploaded image

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        [ValidateInput(false)]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "id,name,info,whatThisTeach,whatToKnow")] Major major, HttpPostedFileBase img)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if(img != null)
                {
                    major.img = new byte[img.ContentLength];
                    img.InputStream.Read(major.img, 0, img.ContentLength);
                }
                else
                {
                    var m = db.Majors.Find(major.id);
                    major.img = m.img;              
                }
                db.Entry(major).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View("Details", major);
        }
```

But when i try to edit data without uploading new image, it gave me this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException   HResult=0x80131509
>   Message=Attaching an entity of type 'MUC.Models.Major' failed because
>   another entity of the same type already has the same primary key
>   value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the
>   state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the
>   graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities
>   are new and have not yet received database-generated key values. In
>   this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track
>   the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or
>   'Modified' as appropriate.   Source=EntityFramework   StackTrace:
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.VerifyRootForAdd(Boolean
>   doAttach, String entitySetName, IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity,
>   EntityEntry existingEntry, EntitySet& entitySet, Boolean&
>   isNoOperation)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.AttachTo(String
>   entitySetName, Object entity)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.<>c__DisplayClassa.<Attach>b__9()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.ActOnSet(Action
>   action, EntityState newState, Object entity, String methodName)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Attach(Object entity)
>
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.set_State(EntityState
>   value)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbEntityEntry`1.set_State(EntityState
>   value)    at MUC.Controllers.MajorsController.Edit(Major major,
>   HttpPostedFileBase img) in
>   C:\Users\miike\Desktop\MUC\MUC\Controllers\MajorsController.cs:line
>   101    at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase
>   controller, Object[] parameters)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.b__39(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__3d()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f()

and here's my Edit view:

```
@model MUC.Models.Major

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Edit</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>


    @using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Majors", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <h4>Major</h4>
            <hr />
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.img, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @if (Model.img != null)
                    {
                        var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(Model.img);
                        var imgsrc = string.Format("data:image/jpg;base64,{0}", base64);
                        <img src="@imgsrc" /><br/>
                        <input type="file" id="img" name="img"/>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <input type="file" id="img" name="img"/>
                    }

                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.img, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.info, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.info, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "info", @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.info, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.whatThisTeach, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.whatThisTeach, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "whatThisTeach" } })
                    <script type="text/javascript">CKEDITOR.replace('whatThisTeach');</script>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.whatThisTeach, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.whatToKnow, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.whatToKnow, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "whatToKnow" } })
                    <script type="text/javascript">CKEDITOR.replace('whatToKnow');</script>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.whatToKnow, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }

    <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You taking the wrong approach. You are editing data so ALWAYS use a view model, and in the POST method you get you data model from the data base and update its properties from the view model - [What is ViewModel in MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Im not quite sure i understand what u meant. But to take my approach. Isnt there anyway that we could maybe just set an instance for the image field when no image is uploaded.

Comment: Did you read the link (and it makes not difference if there is another approach - the correct approach is to use view model)

Answer (score 0):

your code has a problem because img is null and you pass it again
=> **major.img = m.img;**

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question

Comment: m.img is not null here cos i just query it from my database.